# nodejs http JSON API not working

Tags: json, node.js

I want to use an anime database API and get the information of anime shows, heres what i tried to do

```
var http = require("http");
const url = "http://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime?=cowboy%20bebop";
  http.get(url, res => {
   res.setEncoding("utf8");
   let body = "";
   res.on("data", data => {
   body += data;
});
res.on("end", () => {
  body = JSON.parse(body);
  //then do stuff here
});
});
```

and the error i get is

```
undefined:1



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at IncomingMessage.res.on 
(C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\project\index.js:113:17)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

line 113 is

```
    body = JSON.parse(body);
```

(from the first snippet of code)

the documentation to the API is [here](http://docs.kitsu.apiary.io/introduction/json-api).

Comment: Whats inside your `body` variable before you try to parse it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json  directly on the response you can do async call for json ..

Comment: Your api call is returning the status code 301, so your body is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(body);
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

is thrown when `body` is having invalid json. Check the string value and make sure it is in json format and without any errors.

JSON.parse which can give you "unexpected end of input" errors if the supplied byte length does not match the data.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving the API an invalid JSON:API query in the request (which causes it to return a HTML error page unfortunately)

You want to use the filter query like so: `http://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime?filter[text]=cowboy%20bebop`